# scribd documents images and text blurr CSS

Tags: dom

I really hate websites that blur text or documents and make you pay for free information especially when all you need is a little but of JS and you get all the info for free

here is a hack you can use for docs on scribd dot com
just make sure to scroll to the bottom before you run the code 
or you will have to re run it

```
 //// get rid of damn sign up box
l = document.getElementsByClassName("promo").length
for(i=0; i<l; i++){
   document.getElementsByClassName("promo")[i].style.display ="none"
}
 ///Fix the txt
l2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text_layer").length
for(i=0; i<l2; i++){
     document.getElementsByClassName("text_layer")[i].style.textShadow = "black 3px 2px 4px"
}
 //// fix the images 
  l3 = document.getElementsByClassName('absimg').length
  for(i=0; i<l3; i++){
      document.getElementsByClassName('absimg')[i].style.opacity = "100"
  }
```